# Как можно прочитать текст вопроса через StackExchange API?

Tags: stackoverflow-api, stackexchange-api

Хотел бы использовать [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), чтобы получать текст вопросов, однако в секции, связанной с вопросами, нужного метода я не нашёл, возвращается только заголовок (title) вопроса. Есть ли возможность получать текст вопросов через официальное API или нужно применять парсинг HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая возможность есть, для этого передайте параметр `filter` со значением `withbody`, например:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/1515073?site=ru.stackoverflow&filter=withbody

Однако содержимое вопроса приходит в поле `body` в HTML-формате, и вам все равно придется использовать HTML-парсер.

Другие возможные значения параметра `filter` смотрите [в документации](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).